# How do you put lines like in ImpactChallenge Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I went on the impactchallenge website and found the lines making a border like structure for every column. i am curious how do i put that on my website.
the website is http://impactchallenge.withgoogle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="border"> bipin kumar pal</div>


.border {
    border: 5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
    padding: 5px;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
    outline: 5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
     box-shadow:
        0 0 0 10px hsl(0, 0%, 80%),
        0 0 0 15px hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    color:#fff;

}
```

I thing as you like this type work.